# Reject request in AWS API Gateway for certain IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

Is there a way to reject a request in the Integration Request for certain IPs?

Currently I have this code, which works, but the request still passes through to my Lambda function and I still return the regular result body.  I'm trying to stop the request altogether before hitting the Lambda fn.

```
#if($context.identity.sourceIp != "123.45.55.43")
  {
    "errorMessage" : "Error, not authorized"
  }
#end
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AWS API Gateway: limit requests from a single IP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38444923/aws-api-gateway-limit-requests-from-a-single-ip)

Comment: @AndyHayden I don't think it's a dupe.  Not trying to limit but actually stop, and I think I found a workable (for me) solution below.

Comment: If you use CloudFront / WAF (as in that answer) you can stop. While limiting is not precisely the same it's essentially the same (specifically the solution is the same).

Comment: @AndyHayden I think they are distinctly different because I couldn't apply the answer below to the question in the "possible dupe" post.  The answer below provides the shortest route to stopping a request.

Comment: True, but your answer happens in Lambda (after API Gateway) IIUC. :)

Comment: I think you're right, which is why I'm amazed the invocation count/errors didn't increase in the Lambda dashboard but they did in the Gateway... black box, who knows. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not pretty, but this is what I came up with:  passing a broken request when the IP doesn't match what I want.  In this example, I only want requests from `123.45.55.43` to pass through, and everything else should fail - and I am not concerned about providing an appropriate response to the client.  Since `$broken` isn't defined, we pass nothing on to the Lambda fn.

```
#if($context.identity.sourceIp == "123.45.55.43")
  {
    "source_ip": "$context.identity.sourceIp"
  }
#else
  $broken
#end
```

The API ends up with 400 errors, but the Lambda function doesn't show any new invocations/errors in its dashboard. Works for me.